# Hystrix sees List as incompatible return type in

Tags: hystrix

I have the following Hystrix fallback

```
public List<Data> getDataFallback(String id, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, Throwable t) {
    log.warn("Could not get data");
    throw new DataException(ErrorMessage.builder()
            .code(COULD_NOT_GET_DATA.name())
            .internalMessage(t.getMessage())
            .build());
}
```

It is attached to the following method

```
@Override
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getDataFallback")
public List<Data> getData(String id, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    return repository.find(id, startDate, endDate);
}
```

When running JUnit tests, and presumably also when running the service, I get the following error when running the getData-method

```
com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.exception.FallbackDefinitionException: Incompatible return types. 
Command method: public java.util.List package.class.getData(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate);
Fallback method: public java.util.List package.class.getDataFallback(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.Throwable);
Hint: Different size of types variables.
Command  type literals size = 2: [java.util.List<package.Data>, class package.Data]
Fallback type literals size = 1: [interface java.util.List]
```

If I wrap the list in a wrapper object, the exact same configuration works without a hitch. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Method Return type 
and Parameter should be same 
only one extra argument (Throwable throwable)

```
@GetMapping("/msg")
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallBackGetUsers")
public String localMessage() {
    return userServices.localMassage();

}

/*
 * fallBack method parameter should be same and One Extra parameter will be
 * there only  and Return type also same


 */
public String  fallBackGetUsers(Throwable throwable) {
    return "fallback";
}
```